# Iterated forcing and CH

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, continuum-hypothesis

I need some help with this theorem: if $P_\beta=\langle P_\alpha,\dot{Q}_\alpha:\alpha\leq\beta\rangle$, $\beta<\omega_2$, is a CSI of proper forcings, $P_\alpha\Vdash \lvert \dot{Q}_\alpha\rvert\leq\aleph_1$, and CH holds in the ground model, then $P_\beta$ forces the CH in the generic extension.

A proof of this fact appears in the Handbook, but I need a diferent one. Just for simplicity, suppose $\beta=\omega$, then the problem is how to prove that $P_\omega$ forces the CH. Can someone give a clue or an idea of how to proceed?

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't mind seeing a more direct proof myself if there is one, but why do you _need_ a different proof?

Comment: I agree with Gupta, seeing another would be nice.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a sketch.
We may assume that each $\dot Q_\alpha$ has $\omega_1$ as its universe; in which case the underlying set of $P_{\alpha+1}$ can be taken to be $P_\alpha\times\omega_1$ and the ordering defined as usual. This shows that, by induction each $P_n$ has cardinality $\aleph_1$ (at most) and, by CH, so does $P_\omega$. As $P_\omega$ is proper for every name $\dot x$ of a real and every $p\in P_\omega$ there are $q\le p$ and a countable subset $\dot y$ of $P_\omega\times\omega$ (which then acts as a name of a subset of $\omega$) such that $q$ forces $\dot x=\dot y$. This means that those countable names produces the power set of $\omega$, so that, by CH again, in $V^{P_\omega}$ there are $\aleph_1$ many subsets of $\omega$.

Comment: I'd believe it if you said, "As $P_{\omega}$ is ccc" instead of "proper," how does properness tell us there is some $q \leq p$ and a countable name $\dot{y}$ such that $q \Vdash \dot{x} = \dot{y}$?

Comment: Given $p$ and $\dot x$ (a subset of $P_\omega\times\omega$), take a countable elementary substructure $M$ of $H(\kappa)$ ($\kappa$ large enough) that contains $P_\omega$, $p$ and $\dot x$; take $q\le p$ that is $(M,P_\omega)$-generic. Then $q$ forces that $\dot x$ and $M\cap \dot x$ are the same real.

Comment: I am concerned about the cardinality; I think even $P*\dot{Q}$ might have cardinality $2^{\aleph_1}$. It's true we can take the underlying set of $\dot{Q}_\alpha$ to be forced to be $\omega_1$. But $P*Q$ consists of pairs $p,q$ where $q$ is a name for an element of $Q$ (ie of $\omega_1$). If $P$ has cardinality $\aleph_1$ there might be $2^{\aleph_1}$ such names.

Comment: @KP, Yes I see, thanks.  
@Justin, $p \Vdash \dot{q} \in \omega_1$ then there is $p' \leq p$ and an ordinal $\alpha \in \omega_1$ such that $p' \Vdash \dot{q} = \alpha$.  So $P \times \omega_1$ is dense in $P \ast \dot{Q}$, so we can just assume we're adding copies of $\omega_1$ at each stage of the iteration.

Comment: Hm... I'm still suspicious. Then, assuming CH, you should be able to prove (without any assumptions about properness) that any countable support iteration of forcings of length less than $\omega_2$ is (essentially) of size $\aleph_1$ itself. But then a delta-system argument gives that an $\omega_2$ length iteration of such forcings is $\aleph_2$-ccc. I don't have a counterexample, but whenever I've seen this theorem proven it has always used the properness assumption. Am I mistaken?

Comment: (of course in the above comment i mean iterations of sized aleph_1 forcings)

Comment: Is the assumption of properness necessary in the arguments you've seen? I've seen something similar when proving the consistency of PFA from the consistency of a supercompact. One builds an iteration $P_{\kappa}$ and proves that it has $\kappa$-c.c. using Fodor's Lemma and a Delta-system argument. One uses the fact that at each stage, we can restrict our choice of names to belong to $V_{\beta}$ for some $\beta < \kappa$. Although the iteration consists of proper forcings in this situation, establishing the $\kappa$-c.c. of this iteration doesn't actually use properness as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Justin: For such an assumption, it is of course essential that $\aleph_1$ is not collapsed throughout the iteration (assuming $\dot{\aleph}_1$ is used rather than $\check{\aleph}_1$). This is of course guaranteed by the properness of the forcing so maybe $\aleph_1$-preserving is sufficient for your conclusion?  I'd have to think more about this.  @Amit: Yes, your argument does not require properness; so long as $\kappa$ is inaccessible and the forcing at each stage has hereditary size less than $\kappa$, the bounded support iteration of length $\kappa$ should always be $\kappa$-c.c.

Comment: @Jason: I agree with all that you have said... but I'm worried because of say Theorem 2.10 in Abraham's article Proper Forcing which assumes properness, and has a much more involved proof. (Also consider the first sentence of his proof). I feel like if a more general thing is true, with a more obvious proof like that, he would be aware of it and have used it. So I still worry there is some technical detail we are missing. This theorem is stated in some other places in a similar way.

Comment: Ok... I think I see the mistake. It's at the limit stages. It is true that in a two-step (or any n-step iteration) there is a dense set of conditions at which all the names are determined. But this is not true for limit stages. (For example, compare a countable product of Cohen forcings with a countable iteration of them. The former can collapse the continuum). The problem is that since the supports are not finite, the omega-stage iteration is not just the union of all the finite stage ones. So I don't think P_omega has cardinality omega_1.

Comment: Justin, assuming we're just adding copies of $\omega_1$ at successor stages, $P_{\omega}$ will be a subset of $\omega_1^{\omega}$ which has size $\omega_1$ assuming CH.  I think KP's argument holds for $\beta < \omega_1$.  But for $\omega_1 \leq \beta < \omega_2$, your objection sounds right, so perhaps the argument in the handbook can't be improved.

Comment: Amit: I think that you cannot view P_omega as a subset of omega_1^omega. The argument that works for finite steps won't work for P_omega. You would have to strengthen conditions countably many times to make every name determined. In the finite support case you are right, because the omega stage is the union of the finite stages, but not so here. (I may be incorrect, but then I would like to see an argument showing the forcing equivalence of P_omega and a poset of size omega_1. I agree hundred percent with what you said about the two-step iteration)

Comment: Justin, are you alright with saying that for each $n$, $P_n = \prod _1 ^n \omega _1$ (not as partial orders, but simply as sets)?  If so, then by definition of countable support iteration, $P_{\omega}$ will be exactly $\omega _1^{\omega}$, which has size $2^{\omega}$.  In general this could be huge, but it's because we're assuming CH that we can say this has size $\omega _1$.  In the finite support case, we don't need the CH assumption, since $P_{\omega}$ would essentially be $\omega_1 ^{< \omega}$ which has size $\omega_1$.

Comment: Hmm... but I see what you're saying about strengthening countably many times.  I'll think about it.

Comment: Yeah I'm stumped.  There's clearly a problem with strengthening countably many times, but there's something about this particular case where it seems like things should work.  I'd like to see a concrete example where $\omega_1^n$ is a dense subset of $P_n$ for all $n$ but $\omega_1 ^{\omega}$ is not dense in $P_{\omega}$.

Comment: @Amit: What if you first force to collapse $\aleph_1$ before you take the product forcing of $\omega$ Cohen Reals? In this case, $P_{\omega}$ would collapse $(2^{\aleph_1})^{V}$ and so it certainly would not be $\aleph_2$-c.c. @Justin: Yes, I think this is exactly where your concern comes into play. I think the properness notion was motivated by the desire to have a useful family of posets that are closed under countable support iterations; $\aleph_1$-preserving is not in general such a family as we can wind up coding something not inherent in any of the posets.

Comment: On the other hand, I don't know whether such a possibility can happen when all stages of forcing are proper, and I don't know whether Abraham was speaking in hypothetical terms or whether he has a proof of this possibility.  Regardless, it seems likely that $P_{\omega}$ can still have size more than $\aleph_1$ and I'd like to see a proof.  MO question? 

Comment: @Jason, are you saying to regard the product of $\omega$ Cohen forcings as a countable support iteration of $\omega$ Cohen forcings?  Assuming CH, the countable product of Cohen forcings collapses $\omega_1$, but the countable iteration of these Cohen forcings will be proper hence will preserve $\omega_1$.

Comment: @Amit: There's a subtle difference here even though the check names for adding a Cohen real represent the same p.o. as the dot names. The difference is in what will constitute the dense sets of $P_{\omega}$.  See e.g., Chapter VIII Exercise (E4) in Kunen: "Let $P_{\omega}$ be defined by countable supports, and let each $\pi_n$ be $(Fn(\omega, 2))^{\check{ }}$.  Show that $P_{\omega}$ collapses $\omega_1$."  More generally, I think you can look at the underlying set of $P_{\omega}$ as $\omega_1^{\omega}$ in each extension, but you will need to mix names making $P_{\omega}$ large.

Comment: Right, the countable support iteration of Cohen forcings (check versions) collapses $\omega_1$.  So this forcing isn't proper.  Since it's a countable support iteration, this would have to mean one of these Cohen forcings isn't proper?

Comment: @Amit: No, the forcing posets to add a Cohen Real are identical in any transitive model of ZFC because they consist of finite subsets of $\omega \times 2$ (i.e., all c.c.c. so all proper). I think the issue here is in the definition of an iteration, which Kunen is more relaxed about. Mainly, he allows for names $\langle p, \dot{q}\rangle$ where $p\Vdash\dot{q}\in\dot{Q}$ whereas Jech requires that $\Vdash\dot{q}\in\dot{Q}$. This is a full name issue (e.g., also see Exercise (D3) in Kunen). The problem is that under Kunen's definition, a c.s. iteration of c.c.c. posets many not even be proper.

Answer (score 3):

For any $\alpha < \omega_2$, the forcing notion $P_\alpha$ has a dense subset $P'_\alpha$ of cardinality $\aleph_1$.

This is proved in Shelah's "Proper Forcing" book. Jakob Kellner and I also give a sketch of this proof in our review of Uri Abraham's survey article on proper forcing (MR2768684).

As a consequence, each $P_\alpha$ will satisfy the $\aleph_2$-cc. The rest of the proof is as in the handbook (I do not know any essentially different proof): Counting "nice names" (i.e., names of reals that are defined from countably many antichains) shows that CH is preserved.