# Does small forcing preserve CH?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, continuum-hypothesis

Suppose CH holds and $\mathbb{P}$ is a poset of size $\omega_1$, such that forcing with $\mathbb{P}$ preserves $\omega_1$.  Does forcing with $\mathbb{P}$ preserve CH?  If $\mathbb{P}$ is proper then the answer is yes, see [this question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53452/iterated-forcing-and-ch)  Is this true for improper $\omega_1$-preserving posets of size $\omega_1$?

Comment: Meanwhile, if $\omega_1$ is not preserved, then the answer is no, not necessarily, since when you collapse $\omega_1$ to become countable, the size of $2^\omega$ becomes the ground model $2^{\omega_1}$, which can be very large.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. Let $X$ be a name for a subset of $\omega$. It can be described the following way: for every $i<\omega$ $\{p^i_\alpha:\alpha<\omega_1\}$ a maximal antichain, $\{\varepsilon^i_\alpha:\alpha<\omega_1\}$ where $\varepsilon^i_\alpha\in\{0,1\}$ and $p^i_\alpha$ forces $i\in X$ iff $\varepsilon^i_\alpha=1$. In $V[G]$ the function $i\mapsto h(i)$ is an $\omega\to\omega_1$ map where $p^i_{h(i)}\in G$. As $P$ preserves $\omega_1$, the range of $h$ is bounded, i.e., some $p$ forces that $h(i)<\gamma$ for all $i$, for some $\gamma<\omega_1$. Now the structure $\langle p,\langle p^i_\alpha,\varepsilon^i_\alpha:\alpha<\gamma\rangle\rangle$ fully describes $X$.